# How to find the "most efficient" users on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, users, statistics, top-users

Is there a way to find out who are the most efficient users on StackOverflow (given a certain reputation threshold)?

What I mean by an efficient user is one who has the least amount of posts (either asking or answering) and gained more reputation.

**Example**

Let's look at two hypothetical users (`userA` and `userB`)

**userA**

```
Reputation: 5000
Answers: 250
Questions: 10
```

**userB**

```
Reputation: 5000
Answers: 350
Questions: 100
```

In this example, I define `userA` as the more efficient user since `userA` has been able to reach the same reputation (5000) with less posts.

Of course, there are so many qualitative variables that aren't factoring into my definition (e.g. quality of posts, time of day spent on the site, etc.); however, I'm solely concerned with the quantitative data.

I suppose a simple calculation, for an "efficiency index", could just be to take the sum of the users posts (`250 + 10 = 260 for userA` and `350 + 100 = 450 for userB`) and divide the reputation by sum.

**Example**:

```
userA = 5000 / 260 = 19.23 (higer efficiency index)
userB = 5000 / 450 = 11.11
```

Of course, this is just as simple case. Ideally, It would be nice to ask questions like:

1. Who is the most efficient user under 2,000.
2. Who is the most efficient user between 5,000 and 10,000.
3. Who is the most efficient user overall.

I understand this could be quite tricky and obviously you would want to consider filtering out users that have an artificially high efficiency index.

I appreciate the feedback that the community has to offer. Thanks.

Comment: The way is obviously SEDE. I think you can fetch rep-per-post from there in some way SQL wizards know. I'd be surprised if it provided anything useful though. There are some lucky or well-known one time posters with high ratios I bet. Could maybe solved by introducing a least number of posts to the filter.

Comment: @TIPS Yeah, I was thinking you would want to account for those artificially high efficiency indices from those "lucky" post situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have some results with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/503308/637255/user-effectiveness) (feel free to fork it and experiment yourself, e.g. by setting the reputation limits):

```sql
SELECT u.displayname, u.reputation, COUNT(*) AS numberOfPosts,
  u.reputation / COUNT(*) AS score
  FROM users AS u
  INNER JOIN posts AS p
    ON p.owneruserid = u.id
  GROUP BY u.displayname, u.reputation
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
  ORDER BY score DESC
```

I took a threshold of at least 10 posts, here are the top results:

[image]

Comment: Those are (for the most part) users who have a single highly upvoted answer. Is that really efficiency? Perhaps some limitation on variance would be prudent?

Comment: @Glorfindel This definitely points me in the right direction (+1 for that). However these results are a bit skewed due to them being mostly for single highly upvoted answers as Robert mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Maybe you should filter out the top two scoring posts per user, but it's hard to translate that back into reputation points, given that questions count for +5 and answers for +10, and there's such a thing as the daily reputation limit.

Comment: A minor change to get the user names clickable: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/503356/user-effectiveness

Comment: In your query, why not `u.reputation / numberOfPosts AS score` ?